# How to disassemble floppy disk?

Tags: assembly, floppy, nasm

I want to disassemble floppy disk and assemble it again with `nasm -f bin` command. For example, I want to disassemble MS-DOS `.img` files and assemble it again with `nasm -f bin` command.

I tried to use `ndisasm` command:

```
ndisasm -b 16 File.img
```

Comment: What's the problem and what is it you want us to do about it?

Comment: Perhaps try to mount or extract the img file, then disassemble the binaries it contains?